# Изменить первую цифру если она 8

Tags: javascript

В JS только начинаю разбираться. Нашёл в интернете пример кода на чистом JS для ввода номера телефона.

```
//Маска ввода
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    function setCursorPosition(pos, elem) {
        elem.focus();
        if (elem.setSelectionRange) elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
        else if (elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd("character", pos);
            range.moveStart("character", pos);
            range.select()
        }
    }
    function mask(event) {
        var matrix = "+_ (___) ___-__-__",
        i = 0,
        def = matrix.replace(/\D/g, ""),
        val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
        if (def.length >= val.length) val = def;
        this.value = matrix.replace(/./g, function(a) {
        return /[_\d]/.test(a) && i < val.length ? val.charAt(i++) : i >= val.length ? "" : a
        });
    if (event.type == "blur") {
        if (this.value.length == 2) this.value = ""
    } else setCursorPosition(this.value.length, this)
    };
        var input = document.querySelector(".maskphone");
        input.addEventListener("input", mask, false);
        input.addEventListener("focus", mask, false);
        input.addEventListener("blur", mask, false);
    });
```

Если пользователь копирует номер телефона в поле ввода, и если он начинается не с +7 а с 8, тогда надо 8 менять на 7. Код этот для меня сложен и не понятен. Помогите внедрить нужную функцию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");` — Оно удаляет из введенной строки всё, кроме цифр, для предстоящей замены. Добавил еще один `.replace(/^8/, "7")` где `^` означает 'Начало строки' (это «Регулярные выражения»). Если нужно любую первую цифру заменить на 7, `.replace(/^\d/, "7")` [ d - digit, цифра ].

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var input = document.querySelector(".maskphone");
  
  input.addEventListener("input", mask);
  input.addEventListener("focus", mask);
  input.addEventListener("blur", mask);
  
  /***/
  function mask(event) {
    var blank = "+_ (___) ___-__-__";
    
    var i = 0;
    var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/^8/, "7"); // <---
    
    this.value = blank.replace(/./g, function(char) {
      if (/[_\d]/.test(char) && i < val.length) return val.charAt(i++);
      
      return i >= val.length ? "" : char;
    });
    
    if (event.type == "blur") {
      if (this.value.length == 2) this.value = "";
    } else {
      setCursorPosition(this, this.value.length);
    }
  };
  
  /***/
  function setCursorPosition(elem, pos) {
    elem.focus();
    
    if (elem.setSelectionRange) {    
      elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
      return;
    }
    
    if (elem.createTextRange) {    
      var range = elem.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd("character", pos);
      range.moveStart("character", pos);
      range.select();      
      return;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="maskphone">
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, теперь работает как надо!

Comment: Приведенный выше код работает только на первой форме если таковых несколько на одной странице. Классы названы одинаково. Как сделать чтобы код работал на всех формах на сайте? Не множить же скрипт с другим именем класса - это кстати сработало на сайте где всего 2 формы было. Объясните мне пожалуйста, как модифицировать код чтобы он сработал на 15 формах допустим где все классы будут разные. Или наоборот одинаковые?

Comment: @ВасяСкороход Вместо `var input = document.querySelector(".maskphone");` берем `document.querySelectorAll(".maskphone");` , а следующие три строчки с addEventListener, пихаем в цикл `for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) { input[i].addEventListener('input', mask); /* и  пр. */ }`. Это если с одинаковыми классами. А если с разными, можно сделать функцию `function implement_mask(elem) { elem.addEventListener('input', mask); /* и пр. */ }` и вызвать её для каждого "отдельного класса", `implement_mask(document.querySelector('.ваш-класс'));` Хотя лучше таки выдать всем один класс)

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно в код дописать:

```
var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/^8/, "7").replace(/^9/, "79"); // <---
```

При вводе цифры 9, подставляется 79